# .notifyDataSetChanged() problems

Tags: android, gradle, contextmenu, notifydatasetchanged

I'm making an android to do list app called list track, right now I'm still working on the basics of the app. Anyway I made a context menu for the list view, the context menu only has 1 option, "remove", its meant to remove an item from the list but, when the "remove" option is clicked, the app crashes. I tried running it without the .notifyDataSetChanged() and it worked but I have to click the "add" button before the item is removed, which causes a whole lot of problems.
Here's the code:

```
        package com.drift.listtrack;

      import android.app.*;
      import android.os.*;
      import android.widget.*;
      import java.util.*;
      import android.view.View.*;
      import android.view.*;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.ContextMenu;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
      import android.view.ContextMenu.*;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private ArrayList<String> todoItems;
private ListView list;
private EditText items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    items= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.items);
    Button enter=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);

    todoItems= new ArrayList<String>();
    int resID=R.layout.listrack_item;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, resID, todoItems);
    list.setAdapter(aa);



    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            todoItems.add(0,items.getText().toString());
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            items.setText("");

        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(list);

}

static final private int REMOVE_TODO= Menu.FIRST;



@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(0, REMOVE_TODO, Menu.NONE, R.string.remove); 

}


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
     super.onContextItemSelected(item);
     switch (item.getItemId()){
         case (REMOVE_TODO):{
             AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
                 menuInfo=(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

                 int index=menuInfo.position;

                 removeItem(index);
                 return true;
         }


     }


     return false;
}


private void removeItem(int _index){

    todoItems.remove(_index);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

}



    }
```

And here's my logcat

```
    12-14 19:16:30.155 4786 4786 D     dalvikvm                                     Late-enabling CheckJNI
    12-14 19:16:30.575 4786 4786 D     dalvikvm                                     GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 10% free 7092K/7875K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
    12-14 19:16:30.580 4786 4786 I     dalvikvm-heap                                Grow heap (frag case) to 8.550MB for 1048592-byte allocation
    12-14 19:16:30.600 4786 4816 D     dalvikvm                                     GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 8116K/8967K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
    12-14 19:16:30.615 4786 4788 D     dalvikvm                                     GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 10% free 8116K/8967K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
    12-14 19:16:30.665 4786 4786 D     AbsListView                                  Get MotionRecognitionManager
    12-14 19:16:30.880 4786 4786 D     libEGL                                       loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    12-14 19:16:30.885 4786 4786 D     libEGL                                       loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    12-14 19:16:30.890 4786 4786 D     libEGL                                       loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  Device driver API match
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  Device driver API version: 10
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  User space API version: 10
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
    12-14 19:16:30.965 4786 4786 D     OpenGLRenderer                               Enabling debug mode 0
    12-14 19:16:30.970 4786 4786 E     SensorManager                                thread start
    12-14 19:16:30.970 4786 4786 D     SensorManager                                registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41798610
    12-14 19:16:32.920 4786 4786 D     SensorManager                                unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41798610
    12-14 19:16:32.920 4786 4786 D     Sensors                                      Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
    12-14 19:16:32.920 4786 4786 I     Sensors                                      sendDelay --- 200000000
    12-14 19:16:32.925 4786 4786 D     SensorManager                                JNI - sendDelay
    12-14 19:16:32.930 4786 4786 I     SensorManager                                Set normal delay = true
    12-14 19:16:34.520 4786 4786 W     IInputConnectionWrapper                      showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    12-14 19:16:30.155 4786 4786 D     dalvikvm                                     Late-enabling CheckJNI
    12-14 19:16:30.575 4786 4786 D     dalvikvm                                     GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 10% free 7092K/7875K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
    12-14 19:16:30.580 4786 4786 I     dalvikvm-heap                                Grow heap (frag case) to 8.550MB for 1048592-byte allocation
    12-14 19:16:30.600 4786 4816 D     dalvikvm                                     GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 8116K/8967K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
    12-14 19:16:30.615 4786 4788 D     dalvikvm                                     GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 10% free 8116K/8967K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
    12-14 19:16:30.665 4786 4786 D     AbsListView                                  Get MotionRecognitionManager
    12-14 19:16:30.880 4786 4786 D     libEGL                                       loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    12-14 19:16:30.885 4786 4786 D     libEGL                                       loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    12-14 19:16:30.890 4786 4786 D     libEGL                                       loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  Device driver API match
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  Device driver API version: 10
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  User space API version: 10
    12-14 19:16:30.895 4786 4786 D                                                  mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
    12-14 19:16:30.965 4786 4786 D     OpenGLRenderer                               Enabling debug mode 0
    12-14 19:16:30.970 4786 4786 E     SensorManager                                thread start
    12-14 19:16:30.970 4786 4786 D     SensorManager                                registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41798610
    12-14 19:16:32.920 4786 4786 D     SensorManager                                unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41798610
    12-14 19:16:32.920 4786 4786 D     Sensors                                      Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
    12-14 19:16:32.920 4786 4786 I     Sensors                                      sendDelay --- 200000000
    12-14 19:16:32.925 4786 4786 D     SensorManager                                JNI - sendDelay
    12-14 19:16:32.930 4786 4786 I     SensorManager                                Set normal delay = true
    12-14 19:16:34.520 4786 4786 W     IInputConnectionWrapper                      showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    12-14 19:17:19.575 8036 8036 D     dalvikvm                                     DexOpt: load 22ms, verify+opt 34ms, 316316 bytes
    12-14 19:17:53.365 9751 9751 D     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 Late-enabling CheckJNI
    12-14 19:17:53.645 9751 9751 D     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 10% free 7092K/7875K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
    12-14 19:17:53.645 9751 9751 I     dalvikvm-heap com.drift.listtrack            Grow heap (frag case) to 8.550MB for 1048592-byte allocation
    12-14 19:17:53.670 9751 9753 D     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 10% free 8114K/8967K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 20ms
    12-14 19:17:53.670 9751 9751 D     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
    12-14 19:17:53.670 9751 9770 D     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
    12-14 19:17:53.755 9751 9751 D     AbsListView com.drift.listtrack              Get MotionRecognitionManager
    12-14 19:17:53.820 9751 9751 D     libEGL com.drift.listtrack                   loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    12-14 19:17:53.825 9751 9751 D     libEGL com.drift.listtrack                   loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    12-14 19:17:53.825 9751 9751 D     libEGL com.drift.listtrack                   loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    12-14 19:17:53.830 9751 9751 D      com.drift.listtrack                         Device driver API match
    12-14 19:17:53.830 9751 9751 D      com.drift.listtrack                         Device driver API version: 10
    12-14 19:17:53.830 9751 9751 D      com.drift.listtrack                         User space API version: 10
    12-14 19:17:53.830 9751 9751 D      com.drift.listtrack                         mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
    12-14 19:17:53.875 9751 9751 D     OpenGLRenderer com.drift.listtrack           Enabling debug mode 0
    12-14 19:17:53.880 9751 9751 E     SensorManager com.drift.listtrack            thread start
    12-14 19:17:53.880 9751 9751 D     SensorManager com.drift.listtrack            registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@417b9bb8
    12-14 19:18:00.040 9751 9751 D     AbsListView com.drift.listtrack              Get MotionRecognitionManager
    12-14 19:18:00.105 9751 9753 D     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 GC_CONCURRENT freed 110K, 9% free 8432K/9223K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
    12-14 19:18:00.225 9751 9751 D     SensorManager com.drift.listtrack            unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@417b9bb8
    12-14 19:18:00.225 9751 9751 D     Sensors com.drift.listtrack                  Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
    12-14 19:18:00.225 9751 9751 I     Sensors com.drift.listtrack                  sendDelay --- 200000000
    12-14 19:18:00.225 9751 9751 D     SensorManager com.drift.listtrack            JNI - sendDelay
    12-14 19:18:00.225 9751 9751 I     SensorManager com.drift.listtrack            Set normal delay = true
    12-14 19:18:00.900 9751 9751 D     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           Shutting down VM
    12-14 19:18:00.900 9751 9751 W     dalvikvm com.drift.listtrack                 threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410352a0)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.drift.listtrack.MainActivity.removeItem(MainActivity.java:95)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.drift.listtrack.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:80)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2629)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4034)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:193)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:934)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1287)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3078)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4161)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    12-14 19:18:00.905 9751 9751 E     AndroidRuntime com.drift.listtrack           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this, I think I may have misused the notifyDataSetChanged(). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a NullPointerException because aa object (in the class) is null. The reason is that in onCreate you create another aa object (arraylist) with the same name. You need to assign arraylist to the class variable.

Try:
          aa=new ArrayAdapter(this, resID, todoItems);